# Error at the last minute of submitting my research work COULD NOT UPLOAD FULL PROJECT

Tags: spacing

`\begin{spacing}` on input line 10 ended by `\end{document}`.

I am in big tension I have to submit my research work and I don't know what suddenly happened and I got this error although I have checked many times that `\begin` spacing command is followed by `\end` spacing. Greateful to anyone who can help on this error

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\input{./prem/packages}

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.23}
\input{./coverpage/coverpage.tex}                                              
\newpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\input{./declaration/certif}                                                               
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

  \setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\input{./abstract/abstract}                                                             

\newpage
\input{./ack/acknw}                                                                        

\end{spacing}
\newpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\tableofcontents                                                                            % table of content
\end{spacing}
\newpage

\let\origaddvspace\addvspace
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bf LIST OF FIGURES}
    \setcounter{lofdepth}{2}                              
\end{spacing}
\newpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bf LIST OF TABLES}
    \setcounter{lotdepth}{2}                                  
\end{spacing}

\clearpage
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bf LIST OF TERMS AND ABBREVIATIONS}
\input{./prem/acronyms}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype,title={\bf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~LIST OF TERMS AND ABBREVIATIONS},nonumberlist]                                                      % List of terms and abbreviation

%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={\bf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~LIST OF TERMS AND ABBREVIATIONS},nonumberlist]


\end{spacing}
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{\origaddvspace{#1}}


\mainmatter


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{./chapter1/chapter1-Intro} 

\input{./chapter2/chapter2-literature}

\input{./chapter3a/chapter3a-detection2}


\input{./chapter6/chapter6-detection4}

%\input{./chapter7/chapter7-conclusion}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bf ~~~~~~~~~~~REFERENCES}


%\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{references/references}                                                                           
\newpage 
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\input{publications}                                                                                                          % for publications
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but with this little information no one can really help you. Please try to reduce your problem to a minimal example. E.g., try to comment out blocks of code and see whether the error persists. Is that the only reported error message or are there more/others?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! It seems that your `\begin{spacing} ` is not closed with `\end{spacing}`.

Comment: It is the only error message which suddenly start coming. Earlier my project was running fine

Comment: Error message clearly stated that `\begin{spacing}` environment is ended by `\end{spacing`. Read code again, very carefully. Insert `\end{spacing}` some lines after \begin{spacing}` and see, if error disappear. This for sure not happen suddenly. You made some error in your code. Sorry, but further we cant help you. We don't know your document, out crystal balls are brolken or foggy :-(

Comment: HOW CAN I SHARE MY CODE

Comment: Post a link to your project, if it is online, or add the code to the question, if it is short enough

Comment: But as Zarko says: Check whether all `\begin{spacing}` have an accompanying `\end{spacing}`. There error says that some `\end{spacing}` is missing.

Comment: shared code pls help

Comment: You have two `\begin{spacing}{1.5}`, but just one `\end{spacing}`.

Comment: you probably have one \begin{spacing} too much somewhere.  check the first three input files. They are the most likely candidates.

Comment: @amit, sorry, but you can't expect that we will do for you proofreading! That is imminent your job. BTW, most of your document is unknown to us. Ask some your friend to help you in this. Divide your document on smaller parts (to half) and see, where the error occur.